# How to set Request.IsAuthenticated to true when not using FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, authentication, asp.net-membership

I am using Form Authentication and sending an Aajx request to the server for authentication. Based on the json result, the client decides where to go and what to do. That is the reason I am not using FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage to not interfere the ajax/json response.

In this case Request.IsAuthenticated returns false, even after validating the user with Membership.ValidateUser. Then I set the cookie using

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

Although the second parameter, persistent cookie, is false, the cookie is still valid across browser sessions.

Any idea how to make Request.IsAuthenticated work without using FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage?

Comment: It's possible you're not setting the cookie correctly using an AJAX request...

Comment: Have you tried to follow the msdn instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398896.aspx ?

Comment: This is particularly problematic if you're attempting to generate and return an anti-forgery token in your ajax authentication request (i.e a SPA). Asp.Net will generate the token for a "" user as it assumes no one is currently authenticated.

Answer (score 26):

You need to update the current security principal for the request. When you call `Response. Redirect(...)` a new request is done and the security principal is reinitialized and Request.IsAuthenticated returns true in your case. `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` internally calls `Response. Redirect(...)`. You can manually renew the security principal for the current request like this:

```
public void RenewCurrentUser()
{
    System.Web.HttpCookie authCookie =
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;
        authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        if (authTicket != null && !authTicket.Expired)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket newAuthTicket = authTicket;

            if (FormsAuthentication.SlidingExpiration)
            {
                newAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(authTicket);
            }
            string userData = newAuthTicket.UserData;
            string[] roles = userData.Split(',');

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User =
                new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(newAuthTicket), roles);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Manual renewal isn't required (especially for GenericPrincipal and FormsIdentity), and credentials shouldn't change part-way through a request, which why the cookie is added to the response and then a completely new response/request life cycle is performed. On the next request the cookie created by FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() will be picked up.

Comment: Of course this method can be considered a hack because it doesn't follow the normal forms authentication flow. But it can be useful if you want to check if user is authenticated in the same request where authentication takes part.

Comment: Sometimes though a hack is what you need - I was trying to do things "the right way" and forcing a redirect, and getting into a right state with other systems being redirected :(

Comment: Thanks +Branislav Abadjimarinov this was extremely helpful

Comment: I wrote a controller extension called AjaxRenewPrincipal() using this code and it works great to authenticate on same request! Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

> FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
>
> Method Creates an authentication
>   ticket for the supplied user name and
>   adds it to the cookies collection of
>   the response, or to the URL if you are
>   using cookieless authentication.

Ref: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx)

Have a look at the [Forms Authentication Control Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fw3ef80.aspx). The authentication cookie is set to the response cookie collection, and should be observable at the http protocol level (e.g. use FireCookie or Fiddler2 to verify this).

Membership only verifies a username/password. Neither Membership nor `SetAuthCookie()` will modify the current request. They expect to send the cookie back to the caller, and the *next* request is when the properties like `IsAuthenticated` will return true.

Note that you can override and extend these *automatic* processes using custom `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal`, and hook into the authentication events if you need to.

Also have a look at [Using Forms Authentication with ASP.NET AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398896.aspx)

Comment: I've used Fiddler to view cookies in request and response

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting after a POST is best practice, and should be considered the correct solution.

In some cases, you may still want to find out whether a user is authenticated within the scope of the authentication request (for instance if you are running additional logic after the authentication was performed which is shared with other requests).

In this case, you can reset the value of Request.IsAuthenticated with the following code:

```
// set the forms auth cookie
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, createPersistentCookie);

// reset request.isauthenticated
var authCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
if (authCookie != null)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    if (authTicket != null && !authTicket.Expired)
    {
        var roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(authTicket), roles);
    }
 }
```

See post here: http://abadjimarinov.net/blog/2010/01/24/RenewUserInTheSameRequestInAspdotNET.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

we can use this simply

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);