# Setting roles by using GenericPrincipal instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, roles

Recently I asked a question about [how to use ajax calls to 
authenticate user in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704173/setting-httpcontext-current-user), and I got my answer.

But then is decided to use 'Roles' property of 'GenericPrincipal' class

so I changed my code as follow to contain 'Roles':

```
HttpContext.User = new System.Security.Principal.
                    GenericPrincipal(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(login.LoginName),
                     userRole);
```

In my site.master view, I check to see which kind of roles users 
belongs to and I show appropriate menu, but when I watch 
'HttpContext.Current.User.Identity' values during debugging,
I see m_roles=string[0] and 'IsInRole("Admin")' returns false.

How could it be fixed?

Comment: string[] userRole =new string[]{"Admin"}

Comment: @persianDev in my webconfig i have  <roleManager enabled="false"> because i dont want to get the roles from SQL, thats why Im setting the roles by hand as you did... but exactly right in my controller when i try to check IsInRole("..." i get always false... any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the current thread principle:

```
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

as is shown here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/5f9735a9-096b-47af-963d-e95130cad6b4

Comment: is it applicable to asp.net mvc ?

Comment: its applicable to ASP.NET, and thats what both web forms and MVC use.

Comment: @Adam, I just set the System.Threading.... and in the controller it returns false always... any clue?

Comment: @VAAA I don't know what you mean, no controller code is listed here. Post a new issue and we'll check it out.