# MVC 5 Custom Authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

I have a legacy Application that we're converting to use the MVC 5 Application template.  We have a custom API method, to keep the example simple let's just say it's signature is:

```
bool Login(username, password);
```

How can I set the User as logged in, so that I can use things like the [Authorize] attribute?  For the moment we want the simplest method possible just to get us started developing the site.

I tried implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704173/setting-httpcontext-current-user) to set User.Identity manually. But this is then reset on every subsequent request.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I extracted out the logic to the Account controller.  This handles the Login and stores the result in the Session.  Then I just needed to override the System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute class and AuthoriseCore method as follows:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HomeHealth.Web.Infrastructure
{
    public class HomeHealthAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return WebSession.SdkContext.IsAuthenticated;
        }

    }
}
```

It has some helper code to clean up accessing the Context from the session, but that's irrelevant.  The point is that this is the Attribute/Method you probably want. You can then mark Controllers/Methods with the following:

```
[HomeHealthAuthorize]
public class PatientController : BaseController
```

Then all the checking/redirecting is done for you.